# Best practices for SaaS product package subscription flows?

Tags: users, pricing, flow, subscription, saas

I'm creating a flow of pricing for the Edtech product. I did a competitive analysis regarding this flow but I'm not fully satisfied with these flows.

They follow 1-Home >> 2-Pricing >> 3-Sign up >> 4-Portal Dashboard >> 5-Settings >> 6-Billings >> 7-Chosse plan

You can upgrade and buy a new subscription plan by mentioning the above flow.

I think users should land on the portal pricing page instead of the portal dashboard, but all of the big SaaS product platforms landed on the portal dashboard.

I seeking a good logical reason or reference that explains why they redirected users to the dashboard portal page instead of pricing.

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear to me. You mentioned that users land on the pricing page in step 2, but then indicated they don't. If English isn't your primary language, you might find it helpful to write in your native language and use tools like Google Translate or ChatGPT. This could help us better understand your concern.

Comment: You misunderstood the above flow. I wrote the complete user journey from marketing to the portal dashboard.

As I mentioned above, users go to the home page of the marketing website and then go to their pricing page to choose any plan from the given options, and after that, they sign up/sign in. If the user is an existing customer, they should land on the portal pricing page instead of the dashboard, which I have the main concerns about it.

All platforms land users on the portal's dashboard screen. Hopefully, I make it clear to you what concerns I have with this flow.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that you'd end up at the dashboard. Since, most of the times, these services tend to have different tiers and features. So keeping track of which feature you were signing up for can be tricky.

The best and safest move is to not waste time trying to make sure you are on the right page after sign up, but that you know what the main CTA is once you get to the portal dashboard.

Heroku, a Platform as a Service, pretty much tells you this on the pricing page:

[image: heroku pricing page]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Heroku's use case is different from mine. They make different sections and pricing models for each section, in which users have options for what services need for their app.

In my use case, users choose the plan that best suits their needs. I like Heroku's idea, they tell users what steps to take to buy a plan.

I think so, I do a survey on what page a user would expect after signup if they clicked on the CTA on the pricing page.